# How do i handle the exception "The following section has been defined but not rendered in Layout"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sections

I have run into a problem, as a result of searching i have found out to place a `@RenderSection("SectionName")` in my layout but even that the exception is just popping out don't know how to handle it.
Here is the section defined in my view.

```
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/infiniteScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("div#loading").hide();
        });
        var moreRowsUrl = "/InfiniteScrollDemo/GetCustomers"; //the URL to your ActionMethod
        //var moreRowsUrl = ' Url.RouteUrl("CustomerList")'; //if you have a route defined, you can use an Html helper like Url.RouteUrl
        $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
</script>
}
```

and here is the layout code:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="The First Online Shopping Mall in Afghanistan">
    <meta name="author" content="Naser Dostdar">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title Online Shopping Center</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/price-range.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head>


<body>

    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts")


        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.scrollUp.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/price-range.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion or hints would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:**
My view was not using the Layout when i added the Layout to the view another error is showing up. The error is Section not defined: "scripts".

Comment: Are you sure your view is using this layout?

Comment: Oops no, My bad! when i added the layout to the view i just got another error Section not defined: "scripts". What to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a section that is optional, you need to render it with `required` flag set to false:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: After putting required attribute to false i get no error but instead the section script doesn't work as it should. I mean the primary task for this section is to load more customers once the page is scrolled but it doesn't happen.